# Android JSON getJSONObject not working, incorrect parsing

Tags: android, json, parsing

I cannot figure out why my parsing is not working, this is my JSON:

```
  {  
   "fileVersion":"1.0",
   "graves":[  
      {  
         "ID_grave":"1",
         "ID_line":"1",
         "sequence":"1",
         "persons":[  
            {  
               "ID_person":"1",
               "name":"Janez",
               "surname":"Novak",
               "dateBirth":"1956-08-11",
               "dateDeath":"2014-02-12",
               "important":"0",
               "imp_desc":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "ID_grave":"2",
         "ID_line":"1",
         "sequence":"2",
         "persons":[  
            {  
               "ID_person":"2",
               "name":"Mojca",
               "surname":"Novak",
               "dateBirth":"1953-02-13",
               "dateDeath":"2012-04-08",
               "important":"0",
               "imp_desc":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

This code is working, when I want to get the first JSONObject:

```
 String jsonData = convertStreamToString(in);

         JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);  
         JSONArray name = json.getJSONArray("graves");

for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject grave = name.getJSONObject(i);   
         lineArrayList.add(grave.getString("ID_line"));
         graveArrayList.add(grave.getString("ID_grave"));
}
```

But I would like to get the "persons" array in "graves" object. This should work but it's not, I am getting only the first persons array, where the name is Janez and not the second array where the name is Mojca:

```
    String jsonData = convertStreamToString(in);

         JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);  
         JSONArray name = json.getJSONArray("graves");

    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject grave = name.getJSONObject(i);  
         JSONArray persons = grave.getJSONArray("persons");

         for (int k = 0; k < persons.length(); k++) {   

//The problem was because of the index i, you have to change to k and it will work
          JSONObject grave = persons.getJSONObject(i);
           nameArrayList.add(grave.getString("name"));
          surnameArrayList.add(grave.getString("surname"));

         }

      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

graves is a `JSONArray` and persons is a `JSONArray` into `graves`

```
 for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject grave = name.getJSONObject(i);   
      JSONArray persons = grave.optJSONArray("persons");
      if (persons != null) {
         for (int j = 0; j < persons.length(); j++) {

         }
      }
 }
```

Comment: I am getting only the first array (I am getting the name Janez but not mojca)

Comment: I think you should use k as index for your inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Do your parsing as follows ,

```
String jsonData = convertStreamToString(in);

     JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);  
     JSONArray name = json.getJSONArray("graves");

for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
     JSONObject grave = name.getJSONObject(i);  
     JSONArray persons = grave.getJSONArray("persons");

     for (int k = 0; k < persons.length(); k++) {

      JSONObject grave = persons.getJSONObject(i);
       nameArrayList.add(grave.getString("name"));
      surnameArrayList.add(grave.getString("surname"));

     }

  }
```

Comment: I am getting only the first array (I am getting the name Janez but not mojca)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject grave = name.getJSONObject(i);   
          JSONArray persons = grave.optJSONArray("persons");
          if (persons != null) {
             for (int j = 0; j < persons.length(); j++) {
                     JSONObject grave= persons.getJSONObject(i);
                     lineArrayList.add(grave.getString("ID_line"));
                     //so on..
             }
          }
```

Comment: I am getting only the first array (I am getting the name Janez but not mojca)

Answer (score 0):

Ok only today I discovered that I am getting the data only from the first persons array and from the second where for example is a person with a name Mojca..I tried all the three given solutions but nothing works..